# What is the most efficient code to detect and redirect SNI supported browsers?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, sni

Say, I have a website `mywebsite.com`, hosted using Apache Httpd. Now what I want is that whenever any user types `mywebsite.com` or `www.mywebsite.com` and if the browser supports SNI then it should redirect to `https://www.mywebsite.com` else redirect to `http://www.mywebsite.com`.

So, what is the most efficient way to achieve it ?

Comment: What browsers exactly without SNI are you trying to support? IE on XP?

Comment: all the browsers that does not support SNI @Joachin lsaksson

Comment: Then [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/389818/110203) is pretty much the way you need to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should work

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on|off)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s6
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Windows\sNT\s5
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(.*.symbian.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(.*.blackberry.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Here we are neglecting most of the browsers which does not support SNI and hence for them only the http version would be loaded.

Comment: Is it includes all the user agents which does not support SNI ?

Comment: Not all but you can increase the list with other user agents that does not support SNI. Get a complete list of such user agents from google.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be

```
  #Test if new browser and if so redirect to https
  #new browser is not MSIE 5-8, not Android 0-3,
  #not any symbian and not any blackbery
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\ [5-8] [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Android.*(Mobile)?\ [0-3] [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(.*.symbian.*) [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(.*.blackberry.*) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This ignores MSIE 5-8 which excludes all IE on XP, plus some on VISTA that would work.  But allows XP with chrome, firefox, opera, all of which support SNI on XP.  That at least allows XP users to use https.  Likewise it assumes all symbian, blackbery don't have sni.  And that android 3 does (which tablets do I'm told, phones need 4).

For a different solution you could have

```
  #Could use this to set $_SERVER['SSL_TLS_SNI'] for php
  SetEnv SSL_TLS_SNI %{SSL:SSL_TLS_SNI}
```

This would set $_SERVER['SSL_TLS_SNI'] to either %{SSL:SSL_TLS_SNI} (yeah could be better code), or the domain name.  If you know what is the default cert that apache returns and have access to that domain then in the other domains you could get php to do a test https to the default domain and then check $_SERVER['SSL_TLS_SNI'] to test for SNI before going to https.

Note there is no way to avoid an error message if a non-sni browser does https to a site which needs sni.  The best you can do is

```
  # Test if SNI will work and if not redirect to too old browser page
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_TLS_SNI} =""
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/too-old-browser [L,R=307]
```

The user needs to accept the browser error and continue to website, after which he gets redirected to http and the error page.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used based on the answers above.

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE\s7
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Windows\sNT\s5
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Android.*(Mobile)?\ [0-3] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(.*.symbian.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(.*.blackberry.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This rewrites to http first and then rewrites to https if useragent is not listed.
I dont know if this is bad having two rewrites but I am sure google and other relevant bots prefer indexing https. This way achieves that (I Think :)

My backwards way of doing it but it seems to work. I am sure your better blacklisting browsers and navigating them to HTTP rather than whitelisting browsers as there is way too many to add.

Every site is different and depending on security the above could be an option.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I like your approach. I tried something quite similar, with the aim of avoiding the two redirections by setting an environment variable. Unfortunately, it currently does not work, but I would appreciate you thoughts:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77935905/5263950

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a second server that would only work with SNI and make the page on your first site make an Ajax request to it (possibly with some identifier if needed).

If the client doesn't support SNI, the server will presented with an invalid certificate for the requested host name. Hence, that Ajax request won't work. You could have your initial page react to that failure, as an indication that SNI isn't supported.

Of course, this isn't perfect, but this might be better than having to depend on an explicit list of user agents (depending on the constraints you have). This would be more along the lines of testing client capabilities directly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is inspired from [user3281096's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35325973/5263950).

It is **not working yet** and must be considered **a draft**.

Since most browsers are now supporting HTTPS, the idea is avoid a double redirection, and redirect to HTTP if an only if the browser does not support HTTPS.
For this, an environment variable named HTTP_ONLY is defined and set to 1 (= true) if the browser belongs to some "black" list.

Because the `<If>` and `<Else>` directives available only from Apache 2.4, I had to use `<IfDefine>` instead.

Environment variables and `<IfDefine>` seem tricky to use and so far I could not find a way to make the following code work properly.

The tests were performed with Internet Explorer 11 by uncommenting the line `BrowserMatch "Trident/7" HTTP_ONLY=1` to artificially insert this browser on the list of HTTP-only browsers.

Please comment if you know a way to adapt this code to make it work.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

SetEnv HTTP_ONLY 0

# Set a black list of (some) old browsers that do not support HTTPS
BrowserMatch "MSIE[5-8]" HTTP_ONLY=1
BrowserMatchNoCase "symbian" HTTP_ONLY=1
BrowserMatchNoCase "blackberry" HTTP_ONLY=1

# Activate next line for testing purposes with Internet Explorer 11
# like if it was Internet Explorer 5 to 8. Not sure that it works properly.
# BrowserMatch "Trident/7" HTTP_ONLY=1

# If the browser only supports HTTP, redirect to HTTP instead of HTTPS.
<IfDefine HTTP_ONLY>
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_ONLY} true
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somesite.ext/$1 [R=302,L]
</IfDefine>

# Redirect to HTTPS. Next two lines must be active on remote server.
<IfDefine HTTP_ONLY>
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_ONLY} false
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.somesite.ext/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfDefine>

# Force “www.somesite.ext” instead of just “somesite.ext”
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.somesite\.ext [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) https://www.somesite.ext/$1 [L,R=301]
```